# Put call not working for aws apigateway with S3 Proxy integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, aws-api-gateway

I'm implementing the API gateway with S3 proxy integration. When I hit the API with put call from postman, It works perfectly. But in chrome it not working. Saying

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://********.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/*****/******/***/***/download.jpeg' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

The thing is it works fine when I launch chrome in security disabled mode. I know the problem is with cors. But I also enabled the cors in aws API gateway console. And In security disabled mode, it sending the following header which seems weird

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin : "*"

I cant manually send the response header since I'm using s3 as endpoint.

Comment: Looks like it's related to the pre-flight request failing. Did you add a mock integration with CORS headers for OPTIONS requests as well?

Comment: Yes. I did. Even though it failing and the response of the OPTIONS request is 415 Content unsupported.

Comment: Does your put request include the ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *’ CORS header?

Comment: Yes. It has. The only problem is with the options method. Now its says failed to convert the binary data. Why option method is having actual binary data.